# sed - doesn't append new line EOF and replaces letter not defined

Tags: shell-script, sed, quoting

I am experiencing a strange behavior using a sed command (got to be sed, no awk in this case) and got two questions for you, hoping someone got the skills to explain me what I am doing wrong.

- I want to append a comment and two commands to /etc/sudoers using the following one-liner:

  ```
  sed -i -e '$a\# Provide apache user permissions to run the ban_ip.sh script as part of mod_evasive\n\apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/scripts-tecmint/ban_ip.sh\n\Defaults:apache !requiretty' /etc/sudoers
  ```

  Strage things happening here:

  - The first line (a comment) gets appended at the end of the file directly without an empty line created (just a "design thing" I´d linke to fix)
  - The second line created starts now with *^Gpache* instead of *apache*

Questions:
1. How can I append an emtpy line using my sed one-liner to the end of the file and then having my text inserted after that empty line?
2. What do I need to fix in my one-liner to have sed adding the text I want (2nd line to start with *apache* and not *^Gpache*

Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some particular reason to use sed? Why not ...

```
echo -e '\n# Provide apache user permissions to run the ban_ip.sh script as part of mod_evasive\napache ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/scripts-tecmint/ban_ip.sh\nDefaults:apache !requiretty' >>/etc/sudoers
```

The first 'a' of 'apache' is being escaped by the '\' right before it, resulting in your '^Gpache'.  You should be able to resolve that particular situation by simply removing the '\' after your '\n'.  Starting your comment on a new line could probably be accomplished by inserting a '\n' after your '$a\'.  Maybe something like...

```
sed -i -e '$a\ \n# Provide apache user permissions to run the ban_ip.sh script as part of mod_evasive\napache ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/scripts-tecmint/ban_ip.sh\nDefaults:apache !requiretty' /etc/sudoers
```

Full Disclosure:  I haven't tested either of these solutions.

Comment: Plain `echo` does not translate escape sequences:  use `echo -e` or `printf`

Comment: @glennjackman that's why I included the '-e' switch

Comment: 2nd options works for me. Thanks 'smokes*'

Answer (score 3):

Because the `\a` character is <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> -- you don't need to escape the character after `\n`

For maintainability, I'd recommend slightly reducing the one-liner-ness of it, and use actual newlines to continue the `a` command. This also enables the blank line you want.

```
sed -i -e '$a\
\
# Provide apache user permissions to run the ban_ip.sh script as part of mod_evasive\
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/scripts-tecmint/ban_ip.sh\
Defaults:apache !requiretty' /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Hi glenn, thank you for explaining this to me. While you got the right solution, I am using a yaml script and prefer onliners (bad experience in the past with multi line scripts).